# Key for Decrypt pg_auth Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I want to know user's password to connect database without user input their password database.
I know that password for connect database postgresql is saved in pg_auth. But i dont know how to decrypt it without the key.

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation, [45.8. pg_authid](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-authid.htm):

> Password (possibly encrypted); null if
>   none. If the password is encrypted,
>   this column will contain the string
>   md5 followed by a 32-character
>   hexadecimal MD5 hash. The MD5 hash
>   will be of the user's password
>   concatenated to their username (for
>   example, if user joe has password
>   xyzzy, PostgreSQL will store the md5
>   hash of xyzzyjoe).

In other words most probably this password is md5-encrypted (this is default bahaviour of PostgreSQL) and you can't get plain text, because it's not stored anywhere. For example let's say that I have `postgres` role with `12345` password:

```
SELECT rolpassword FROM pg_authid WHERE rolname LIKE 'postgres';
             rolpassword             
-------------------------------------
 md5738d021d4bc194576641fa9936656836
(1 row)
```

[MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) is one-way hash function, so it's not trivial to restore its argument (however you can try with [John the Ripper](http://www.openwall.com/john/) or using rainbow tables):

```
echo -n "12345postgres" | md5sum
738d021d4bc194576641fa9936656836  -
```

Another (simpler) way is to change [pg_hba.conf](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) authentication method to non-password (for example `ident`).

**EDIT:**

With [HashCat](http://hashcat.net/hashcat/) tool (read EULA before using it) with PostgreSQL's `md5($pass.$salt)` mode you could write (of course it's simplified only CPU brute-force example):

```bsh
echo 738d021d4bc194576641fa9936656836:postgres > hash.txt
time ./hashcat-cli64.bin --hash-mode 1 --attack-mode 3 --bf-cs-buf 0123456789 \
--bf-pw-min 1 --bf-pw-max 5 hash.txt
...
738d021d4bc194576641fa9936656836:postgres:12345
All hashes have been recovered

real    0m0.010s
user    0m0.012s
sys     0m0.004s
```